# How To Join Password Protected IRC Server Using Nodejs IRC Module?

Tags: node.js, irc

I looked at the docs found here: https://node-irc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API.html#client

But I cannot find the place to insert my password. No examples either.

Also, will someone tell me the difference between userName and realName? Because your nickname is specified as the second argument.

Here is what I have:

```
// Create the configuration
var config = {
    options : {channels:['#mychan'], port: 6667, secure: true, userName: 'myname', realName: 'myname'},
    server: "servername",
    botName: "Ray"
};

var irc = require("irc");

var bot = new irc.Client(config.server, config.botName, config.options);

bot.join('#mychan');

bot.say('#mychan', "Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just got this working, so I needed to come back here and post this up. It's painfully simple, but alluded me a bit because of the example code I was copy pasterino'ing.

In your config, you need these three things to hit username / password type IRC channels (this is the bare minimum to do this properly):

```
options: {sasl:true, username: "myBotName", password: "myBotPasswordHere"}
```

Note, SECURE: TRUE is looking for SSL Certs. I don't think this is what you're looking for if you're just attempting nick / password auth. Remove that bit from your options config.

I found my answer in the same place you looked, but if you keep going down to SASL explanation, it's going to tell you about the nick / pass stuff.

https://node-irc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API.html?highlight=sasl

Here is my entire file. I do my config a bit differently. I'm also connected to Twitch.tv's IRC, so my pass is OAUTH.

I just connected and tested it out. This is a copy/paste test from here: http://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-irc but I modified it for Twitch.tv

I got lazy and just stuffed the entire config in after the server / nick. But it worked, and thats what we're going for here lol. My purpose is just a dead simple chat bot I can work with for my stream channel.

WarpSpiderBot is a user I had to register on Twitch.tv to be able to make this work since it needs full blown oauth login creds to hit their IRC channels.

```
// Create the configuration
var config = {
    channels: ["#warpspiderx"],
    server: "irc.twitch.tv",
    username: "warpspiderbot",
    nick: "warpspiderbot",
    password: "oauth:--REDACTED--",
    sasl: true
};

// Get the lib
var irc = require("irc");

// Create the bot name
var bot = new irc.Client(config.server, config.nick, config);

// Listen for joins
bot.addListener("join", function(channel, who) {
    // Welcome them in!
    bot.say(channel, who + "...dude...welcome back!");
});

// Listen for any message, PM said user when he posts
bot.addListener("message", function(from, to, text, message) {
    bot.say(from, "¿Que?");
});

// Listen for any message, say to him/her in the room
bot.addListener("message", function(from, to, text, message) {
    bot.say(config.channels[0], "¿Public que?");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation hints at the existence of a `password` key in `options`. Try setting that?

As for username versus realname, that's a weird distinction made by IRC. Username is a single word, realname can be longer. It shows up in a WHOIS (in irssi, for this example) as:

```
nickname [username@host.example.com]
--  ircname  : Real Name
```

Comment: No luck... is there anyway to get interactive feedback of where this failed? Ugh...

Comment: It's possible that the `irc` module simply doesn't support password authentication. If this is the case, you're probably just out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration worked for me to connect a bot in node.js running on glitch.com to Freenode, where I'd registered the nick:

```
let client = new irc.Client('irc.freenode.net', 'yourname', {
  sasl: true,
  userName: 'yourname',
  password: 'yourpassword',
  secure: true,
  debug: true
});
```

The `userName` field is *case sensitive*.

I found this out because I initially had `username` (all lowercase). But then with `debug` enabled, the log showed that it was sending the right nick but the USER command was sending "nodebot" as the username value.

Changing it to match the documentation [1] exactly fixed the problem.

Note: The `secure` option is not related to the ability to log in. You can remove it if you do not care that your communication is in clear text on the network. Not recommended.